# Global variable initialized to 1 instead of 0 in my C program

Tags: c, arguments, global-variables

If I have, suppose, initialized a global variable F, and print its value in main function, 0 will be printed (as it should be).

But when i pass the argument int F in the main function while declaring the global variable F in exact same way as before, printing the value of F using gcc prints 1.

Can anyone explain why is that?

This is my code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int F;

int main(int F){
    printf("F is %d\n", F);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `F` inside `main` is actually the argument count.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and then you would get some warning about a formal argument shadowing a global variable

Comment: do you know about local and global variables? btw its not static can you still get 0?

Comment: BTW, the formal arguments to `main` are *conventionally* called `int argc` and `char**argv`, and you should follow that convention. Naming `F` the first formal argument to `main` is really confusing

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your answer. I have just started learning programming and was trying to convert Farh to Celc using recursion. Now, I had successfully wrote the program with convert function but was trying to see if I can recursively call the main function to convert.

Comment: What happens if you call your program with a parameter e.g. `./myprog 3` ?

Answer (score 2):

When your main function contains an argument with the same name as a global variable then the stub is refered to the local variable .. not the global variable

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    static int F;

    int main(){
        printf("F is %d", F);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

*But when i pass the argument int F in the main function  ?* that `F` is nothing but argument count i.e `argc`.

In particular case you mentioned global `F` and `F` you declared in `main()` argument are different.

`int main(int F){ printf("F is %d\n", F); return 0; }`

Here `printf()` prints `1` because when you run your executable like `./a.out` no of command line input is `1`, it's similar to `argc`.

Your compiler could have warn you about argument provided to `main()`, compile with `-Wall` flag and read the  warning. Also check the `main()` prototype. From the C standard

> ISO/IEC 9899:1999
>
> §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> ¶1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of intand with no parameters:
>
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
>
> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 2):

In your posted code, `main` has an argument named `F`. Inside `main`, any references to `F` refer that variable, not the global one.

You make life unnecessarily harder by using improper names of variables. Most of the time, the arguments to `main` are named `argc` and `argv` -- argument count and argument values.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) { ... }
```

It's good to use variable names that have meaning. Using `int F;` as a global variable is not meaningful either. Name it such that it is meaningful. Then, you will run into problems like you did a lot less.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was trying to convert Farh to celc using recursion. Then I thought that instead of writing a whole new function to convert, can we recursively call main and convert Farh to Celc in main itself.

Comment: @SharadSharma, that's not a good idea. Use another function to do that. You don't want to write a program that subverts the purpose of `main` -- to act as entry point to user code.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
    
    int F = 0;
    
    void main(int F){
     int C = 5.0 * (F-32.0) / 9;
     printf("%3d Fahr = %d Celc\n", F, C);
     if(F > 300)
      return;
     else
      main(F+20);
     return;
    }
This was my code. I am just a beginner and I know what i did was stupid.

Comment: Yeah. Understood that now. Just a stupid experiment.

Comment: @SharadSharma, don't feel too bad. Most of us have made stupid mistakes along the way. Learn from it and move on to the next task :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make `main()` conform to the requirements of the standard, and you should print the global `F` as well as the argument `F`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int F;

int main(int F, char **G)
{
    printf("F is %d\n", F);
    {
    extern int F;
    printf("%s: F is %d\n", G[0], F);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (from source file `quirky43.c` to program `quirky43`), and run, I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror quirky43.c -o quirky43 
$ ./quirky43
F is 1
quirky43: F is 0
$ ./quirky43 this is why you get command line arguments
F is 9
quirky43: F is 0
$
```

The first `printf()` is printing the first argument to `main()` (conventionally called `argc`, but there's nothing wrong with calling it `F` except that it is unexpected).  The second one prints the global variable `F` (and also the program name, conventionally `argv[0]` but again there's nothing wrong with using `G` except that it is unexpected).  The `extern int F;` inside a set of braces means that `F` in that statement block refers to a variable `F` defined outside the enclosing scope, which means the file scope variable `F` — which, it may be noted, is correctly initialized to `0`.  The `1` comes because you invoked the program without arguments, and the argument count includes the program name.  It's also why the value printed was `9` when 8 arguments were added to the command line.

Note that another good compilation option to use is `-Wshadow`:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow quirky43.c -o quirky43
quirky43.c: In function ‘main’:
quirky43.c:6:14: error: declaration of ‘F’ shadows a global declaration [-Werror=shadow]
 int main(int F, char **G)
          ~~~~^
quirky43.c:4:5: note: shadowed declaration is here
 int F;
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

(Compilation with GCC 8.1.0 on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.)